# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face' (OpenCV and Python)

Tags: python, opencv

I have been trying a lot of things like reinstalling CV2, but this error will not go away.

This is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os

# Path for face image database
path = 'C:\\Users\\lordg_000\\Desktop\\trainer'

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");'
```

Comment: Which version of OpenCV are you using?

Comment: the version is 3.4.3.18

Answer (score 0):

The extension module Opencv_contrib is not installed.

Solution:

```
pip  uninstall opencv-python
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Comment: Uninstall before installing.

Comment: you don't need to uninstall `opencv-python`. Only `pip install opencv-contrib-python` should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

i think the root cause is that:your open-cv and numpy version is too low, and your need to upgrate them. trust me ,i did it ,and it works for me.